# Mailto problema con los simbolos & en body

Tags: html

tengo que añadir a un email un enlace que al hacer click cree otro correo.

Estoy utilizando mailto para hacerlo de manera sencilla pero me encuentro con el problema de que el en el cuerpo del nuevo emial incluyo una url con dos simbolos & los cuales interpreta como comandos.

Este es la sentencia:

info@pepepotamos.es?subject=Pedido%20aceptado&body=http://ti360.pepepotamo.es:8033/wp-admin/post.php?post=4731&action=edit&prefix-change-status=processing"

y este es el resultado en el cuerpo:

http://ti360.hopto.org:8033/wp-admin/post.php?post=4731

Alguien sabria como pasar la url sin que interprete los & como comandos.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que la solución para esto es muy corta y bastaría con usar un URL Encoder para la cadena de texto que deseas y probar a enviarla de nuevo, creo que es la mejor solución.

Answer (score 0):

Del mismo modo que en `subject` utilizas la secuencia `%20` en lugar de un espacio normal, puedes hacer lo mismo para los ampersand (`&`) con la secuencia `%26`, aunque deberías hacerlo para todos los posibles caracteres problemáticos (espacios, barras...).

En este caso el problema es que igual que pones `subject=asunto&body=cuerpo`, está interpretando los `&` dentro del cuerpo como si fueran otros parámetros del mailto. Este problema ocurre cada vez que trabajas con URL dentro de URL, y para eso existen los URL encoder (hay métodos en distintos lenguajes, y [algunas herramientas gráficas](https://www.urlencoder.org/)).

De modo que tu enlace mailto sería el siguiente:

```
mailto:info@pepepotamos.es?subject=Pedido%20aceptado&body=http%3A%2F%2Fti360.pepepotamo.es%3A8033%2Fwp-admin%2Fpost.php%3Fpost%3D4731%26action%3Dedit%26prefix-change-status%3Dprocessing
```

Edit 1: Para generar el enlace mailto, utilicé la herramienta [mailtolink.me](https://mailtolink.me/), que es gratuita y funciona en el navegador. Genera enlaces Mailto con la dirección de destino, asunto, cuerpo y CC/CCO.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha funcionado perfecto!!!!

Comment: @JNBruguer Si la respuesta te ha resuelto el problema, por favor márcala como "respuesta aceptada".